# Remove redundant css styles automatically on serverside

Tags: html, css, request, sass, server-side

I am working on a huge project with more than 30 developers & web-designers 
all adding their own css styles to the site... which is becoming unmaintainable. We are using Git, Php zendframework, memcache, capistrano, compass and sass.

I am looking for a solution such as this:

EXAMPLE

```
Compass Sass => CSS created ( .class1 #idname1 .class2 #idname2 .class3 #idname3...)
PHP =>  uniquepagename.html required ( .class1 #idname1 )
```

RESULT:  all the css and html is sent to the client. But...

What if the css sent with the page could contain only the css the actual page.html needs?

Is there such a system out there?

PS: yes we are using compression and are minifying on the server side our CSS and JS (serving only 1 css file (32kb and growing) 1 js file(119kb and growing) etc) still the css file is to heavy for our 11 dedicated servers (we serve 12 countries in Europe)

Comment: What for - just to save a couple of bytes' traffic? That will hardly make sense, will it? I totally see your point about maintenance. But it sounds like you're looking to strip unneeded CSS at output time, which sounds pointless, expensive, and imperfect - what about CSS classes that are assigned dynamically using JavaScript?

Comment: This would be pretty terrible for the user.  It's better for them to receive a large file that is cached than to request a new CSS file on every single page they visit.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is not, analyzing a whole site live to send back only needed CSS would potentially require longer than just sending the CSS and let the client do its work. Also each request would potentially require a little different CSS instead of just using the complete one out of the cache.

The best way always seems to minify and maybe merge the CSS (merge like with CSS Merge)

Comment: As i cant yet answer directly but it doesnt get out of my Mind @Christoph No, just no. More requests is usually much worse than 1 huge request. Feel free to benchmark this your own and nobody cares how a productive CSS file looks. Also the Lifetime can be easily defined manual and i dont see a point in diff the files because of that. If you have changes (which usually is not all 10 minutes) just add ?NEW_RANDOM_ID to the CSS and it gets recached.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation for web performance is to combine and condense your CSS (even the un-needed ones) in order to minimize the number of requests to the server as well as take advantage of client/server technologies like caching.

So, while it may make sense what you're trying to achieve, it is actually advisable to stuff all your CSS into as few files as possible that are requested less frequently and cached according to their expected life span.

HTH

** EDIT:** Updated answer to include comments by @Christoph

Comment: stuffing everything into one css has the following problem: 1) huge bulky css-file 2) possibly short cache durations. It's better to split it into (as few as possible) different files like for corefuncitonality which remains static for long time and stuff with short lifecycles.

Comment: You're right. point #1 is usually handled with minification and compression, but point #2 is well said.